# Remove Trailing / from URL .Netcore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, url-rewriting

I am trying to remove trailing / from URL but nothing seems to work , My code does remove multiple slases at the end so :

```
https://www/abc.com/xxx////  becomes https://www/abc.com/xxx
```

But

```
https://www/abc.com/xxx/ stays https://www/abc.com/xxx/
```

Here is my code below and also to mention tried many things and order of rules still same thing every time:

```
 var rewriteOptions = new RewriteOptions()
 .Add(ctx =>
{
    var request = ctx.HttpContext.Request;
    var path = request.Path.Value;

    if (path.Length > 1 && path.EndsWith("/"))
    {
        path = path.TrimEnd('/');
    }

    // Check if URL is not already lowercase
    if (path.ToLowerInvariant() != path)
    {
        // Convert to lowercase
        var newPath = path.ToLowerInvariant();
        var newUrl = $"{newPath}{request.QueryString}";
        ctx.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(newUrl, permanent: true);
    }
})
.AddRedirect(@"^(.*?)/{2,}$", "$1");

 application.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);

 application.UseResponseCaching();
```

Thank you

Comment: You Could you try `.AddRedirect(@"^(.*?)/{1,}$", "$1".ToLowerInvariant());` Because, `^(.*?)/{2,}$` was meant to match URLs with two or more consecutive slashes at the end. However, it didn't cover the case of a single trailing slash, which is a common scenario. But `(.*)/$` matches any characters followed by a single trailing slash, covering both cases more effectively. This `.AddRedirect(@"(.*)/$", "$1", 301);` can also be valid.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Testing hope it works :)

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron  Same things works on multiple slashes, change to lower case but wont remove the trailing single slash

Comment: Could you please try the updated one, which is `.AddRedirect(@"^(.*?)/$", "$1", permanent: true);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop while it finds a real charecter.

```cs
static string trimTrailingSlash(string url)
{
    while (url.EndsWith("/")) //This is the loop which we use to trim the end.
    {
        url = url.TrimEnd('/'); //Trim the last charecter
    }
    return url;
}


//call the method
trimTrailingSlash("https://www/abc.com/xxx////") //becomes https://www/abc.com/xxx
trimTainlingSlash("https://www/abc.com/xxx/") //stays https://www/abc.com/xxx/
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to remove trailing / from URL but nothing seems to work ,
> My code does remove multiple slases at the end.

Well according to your current syntax `^(.*?)/{2,}$` actualy was meant to match URLs with two or more consecutive slashes at the end. But based on your requirement, it didn't cover the case of a single trailing slash, which is a common scenario.

In order to fix that, you could refactor this expression  to [`(.*)/$`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-8.0#regex-examples) which would matches any characters followed by a single trailing slash, covering both cases more effectively you could refactor as following:

```
.AddRedirect(@"^(.*?)/$", "$1", permanent: true);
```

Even this can also be valid:

```
.AddRedirect(@"(.*)/$", "$1", 301);
```

**Note:** Last parameter would handle status code 301 in AddRedirect method to signify permanent redirection. This should now properly remove the [trailing slash from URLs and redirect URLs with multiple trailing slashes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-8.0#regex-examples).

In addition, please have a look at the following expression:

[image]

You could [refer to this offical document that might be resourceful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-8.0#regex-examples) for you.

Comment: Tried everything above but it does not remove the single trailing slash.

Comment: Sad to hear that, do you have installed IIS rewrite module in your server? In additon, you can also this this `(.*[^/])$` the 2nd yellow mark wihtin the screenshot of my answer.

Comment: Ok trying that.

Comment: Added it to baseApi controller class.

Answer (score 0):

Added:

```
public abstract partial class BasePublicController : BaseController
{
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
   {
    base.OnActionExecuting(context);

    var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value;

    // Check if the URL ends with a slash and is longer than 1 character
    if (path.Length > 1 && path.EndsWith("/"))
    {
        // Remove the trailing slash
        var newPath = path.TrimEnd('/');

        // Reconstruct the URL without the trailing slash
        var newUrl = $"{context.HttpContext.Request.Scheme}://{context.HttpContext.Request.Host}{newPath}{context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString}";

        // Redirect permanently to the new URL
        context.Result = new RedirectResult(newUrl, permanent: true);
        
   }
}
```

This is base class for all controllers which solve the issue.